# HTML Elements Moving on Page Reload - Chrome Only?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

I am experiencing some trouble where some floated elements will be displayed improperly occasionally on page refresh. This behavior has only been recorded in Chrome (36.0.1985.143m) and also Steam Browser. This behavior occurs on Mac OS X 10.9.4, Mac OS X 10.7, Mac OS X 10.6.8, and Windows 7.

Tested include Safari 7.0.6 over Mac OS X 10.9.4, Safari 7.0.6 over Mac OS X 10.7, Firefox 3.6.10 over Mac OS X 10.6.8, Safari 5.1.10 Mac OS X 10.6.8, Firefox 31 over Windows 7, IE11 over Windows 7, IE9 over Windows 7.

I am running ColdFusion 9.0.2 over IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. However, there is currently ZERO server-side scripting being done on this page (or any other related resources). 
**Update:** Currently using server-side scripting to show or hide the divs based on the section parameter in the query string. That is all.

Here is the link to my demo. For those who prefer source, it is below. http://craftdeck.com/mockup2/profile.cfm?section=Store

Here is the rendered HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Craft Deck</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/profile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/froogaloop.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/profile.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="userFunctions">
        <div id="logo">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="functions">
            <span>
              Create Account
            </span>
            <span>
              Login
            </span>
            <span>
              About
            </span>
            <span>
              Contact
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span style="clear:both; height:0; line-height:0;">&nbsp;</span>
      <div id="profileHeader">
        <div id="displayImage">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="verifiedID">
          <span class="title">Verified Identification</span>
          <span class="idType">
            <img alt="Checkmark" src="images/VerifiedIDCheckmark.png" /><span>Email</span>
            <img alt="Checkmark" src="images/VerifiedIDCheckmark.png" /><span>Facebook</span>
            <img alt="RedX" src="images/VerifiedIDX.png" /><span>Twitter</span>
            <img alt="OnlineDot" src="images/VerifiedIDOnline.png" /><span>Online</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="bannerText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.         Nullam in lacus neque. Proin eget sapien quis odio pulvinar adipiscing non eget odio. Nam     congue iaculis congue. Mauris volutpat elit adipiscing velit consectetur iaculis. In aliquam ipsum risus, a luctus dolor ullamcorper eget. Proin in pulvinar sapien. Nam diam ipsum, malesuada aliquam est et, vestibulum bibendum sapien. Ut congue enim magna, ac pretium tellus cursus vel.

Aenean non molestie nisi. Fusce et massa eu felis faucibus molestie vitae a enim. Pellentesque convallis, nunc ut facilisis adipiscing, dui libero dignissim dui, at mattis ipsum mauris vel mauris. Vestibulum quis nibh id nibh luctus dictum et in augue. Pellentesque suscipit fringilla ipsum. Vestibulum ac dictum nisl. Suspendisse id bibendum lacus. Aliquam non ligula ornare, mollis nulla vel, tincidunt augue.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div> 
    <div id="content">
      <div id="navigation">
        <span class="navButton">Store</span>
        <span class="navButton">Reviews</span>
        <span class="navButton" style="border:0 !important;">Chat</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS

```
body {
  background-color:#F1F2F2;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:'Open Sans',Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:15px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  outline:none;
  color:#404041;
}
div {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#profileHeader {
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:175px;
  font-size:12px;
}
#userFunctions {
  width:960px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#userFunctions span {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#logo {
  margin-top:10px;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url('../images/Logo-Orange.png');
  background-position:top left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#functions {
  width:auto;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
}
#functions span {
  margin-left:16px;
  margin-right:4px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:12px;
}
#profileHeader div {
  display:inline-block;
}
#displayImage {
  width:175px;
  height:175px;
  margin-right:2px;
  background-image:url('../images/axe-guy.jpg');
  border-right-width:2px;
  border-right-style:solid;
  border-right-color:#F1F2F2;
}
#bannerText {
  width:570px;
  height:155px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  border-right:2px solid #F1F2F2;
}
#verifiedID {
  width:165px;
  height:175px;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:14px;
}
#verifiedID .title {
  height:30px;
  width:165px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:15px;
  line-height:30px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #F1F2F2;
}
#verifiedID .idType {
  width:165px;
  height:143px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 0 0 5px;
  line-height:22px;
  font-size:13px;
}
#verifiedID .idType img {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
#verifiedID .idType span {
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  width:138px;
  text-indent:5px;
  display:inline;
}
#idTypes {
  width:165px;
  height:130px;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:13px;
}
#navigation {
  width:960px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#F15A29;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.navButton {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:13px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:316px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  border-right:2px solid #F1F2F2;
}
.navButton .active {
  background-color:#939598;
}
/*#headerPadding {
  background-color:#E9E9E9;
  height:20px;
}    
#bannerImage {
  width:960px;
  background-image:url('../images/Creative-People.png');
  background-size:100%;
  height:100px;
  margin:110px auto 71px;
}
#searchForm * {
  outline:none;
  border:0;
}
#searchForm input,select {
  margin:0 12px;
  background-color:#FFF; 
  height:36px; 
  font-family:'Open Sans';
  text-align:left;
  text-indent:10px;
  color:#999;
  width:189px;
}
#searchForm select {
  height:38px;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  border-radius:0;
  -webkit-border-radius:0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent:10px;
}
#searchForm #searchSubmit {
  width:93px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px #FFF solid;
  background-color:#F05A28;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  text-indent:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#content {
  background:#F1F2F2;
  width:100%;
  height:1090px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
#search {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:26px;
  text-align:center;
}
#searchResults {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.listing {
  width:320px;
  height:212px;
  float:left;
  background-image:url('../images/craftdeck_default_item_1.png');
}
.listing img {
  opacity:0.3;
}
.listing .pricetag {
  height:53px;
  width:123px;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  position:relative;
  background-image:url('../images/Pricetag-Full.png');
  bottom:212px;
  left:193px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:53px;
  text-indent:35px;
}
.listing .socialMedia {
  width:84px;
  height:27px;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  bottom:87px;
  left:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -o-border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  position:relative;
}
.listing .socialMedia img {
  opacity:1;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#playVideo {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#filters {
  width:30px;
  height:424px;
  background-color:#6D6E70;
  background-color:rgba(167,169,171,0.8);
  position:relative;
  left:290px;
  bottom:295px;
  z-index:1000;
}
#filters img {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#viewMore {
  width:126px;
  height:31px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border-radius:0;
  border-bottom-right-radius:13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:13px;
  background-color:#D1D2D4;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:31px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}*/
```

**Update:**

I have made some updates to the mockup as we need to progress this thing ASAP! I have determined the bug occurs far more often whilst navigating between the sections of the profile using the "Shop", "Reviews", and "Chat" navigation buttons.

**Update2:**

I have now installed a modified version (for HTML5 documents) Eric Meyer's CSS reset into the profile.css file. There has been no change in the bug's status however.

**Update3:**

As pointed out by bracketsage in a comment below, embedded CSS DOES NOT have this problem. I have included an HTML commented version of the stylesheet embedded in the head tag. If this is uncommented and the link to the external stylesheet removed, this bug NO LONGER OCCURS... Interesting.

**Update4:**

I have now embedded the stylesheet and removed the references to the external stylesheets (the old one, as well as the updated one from user Bracketsage below). They can be seen viewing source of HTML as HTML comments in the head tag. If external stylesheets are referenced, bug is still present... **I've removed the bug temporarily because developing over this bug is annoying as f*****

Comment: You might want to remove the debug information from that page.

Comment: Sorry, updated link and added server-side parameter to default page.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with ColdFusion?

Comment: The only similar thing I could find talked about improperly encoded files or something. So I tried a few things.. and couldn't get anywhere.

(1). I did notice that if you embed the css straight in, there's no problem and (2). There's not any kind of style name causing the issue. Like some sort of random reserved word, I renamed all your styles and no luck.

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with ColdFusion... But that doesn't mean I shouldn't include information about my server to help us figure it out... Thanks for the update bracketsage! I will be looking at some of these as well, thanks.

Comment: Bracketsage, THAT is INTERESTING!! WOW. Embedded styles are totally unaffected by this bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have it working..

One of the things I did to this file was replace \r with nothing and use \n strictly because it was bugging me in regex tests. Repeated refreshes in chrome are keeping everything in place.

Another thing was to put the mass-tag-fixer all on one line. I don't know that this helped.

I did also remove styles you'd commented out, and admittedly, the comment for the mass-tag-refixer. I know you'll want to put that back.

I renamed profile.css to new.css (only for my testing) and suggest you do something similar only so a random cache doesn't disappoint you.

Here's the css exactly as I have it in new.css.

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,  footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}



body {
  background-color:#F1F2F2;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:'Open Sans',Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:15px;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  outline:none;
  color:#404041;
}
div {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#profileHeader {
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:12px;
  height:auto;
}
#userFunctions {
  width:960px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#userFunctions span {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#logo {
  margin-top:10px;
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  background-image:url('../images/Logo-Orange.png');
  background-position:top left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#functions {
  width:auto;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#functions span {
  margin-left:16px;
  margin-right:4px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:12px;
}
#profileHeader div {
  display:inline-block;
}
#displayImage {
  width:175px;
  height:175px;
  background-image:url('../images/axe-guy.jpg');
  border-right-width:2px;
  border-right-style:solid;
  border-right-color:#F1F2F2;
}
#bannerText {
  width:560px;
  height:155px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  border-right:2px solid #F1F2F2;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#verifiedID {
  width:170px;
  height:175px;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:14px;

}
#verifiedID .title {
  height:30px;
  width:155px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:10px;
  line-height:30px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #F1F2F2;
}
#verifiedID .idType {
  width:160px;
  height:135px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 0 0 5px;
  line-height:22px;
  font-size:13px;
}
#verifiedID .idType img {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
#verifiedID .idType span {
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  width:138px;
  text-indent:5px;
  display:inline;
}
#idTypes {
  width:165px;
  height:130px;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:13px;
}
#navigation {
  width:960px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#F15A29;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.navButton {
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:13px;
  width:318px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  border-right:2px solid #F1F2F2;
  float:left;
}
.navButton .active {
  background-color:#939598;
}
#shopListings {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.listing {
  width:320px;
  height:212px;
  float:left;
  background-image:url('../images/craftdeck_default_item_1.png');
}
.listing img {
  opacity:0.3;
}
.listing .pricetag {
  height:53px;
  width:123px;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  position:relative;
  background-image:url('../images/Pricetag-Full.png');
  bottom:212px;
  left:193px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:53px;
  text-indent:35px;
}
.listing .socialMedia {
  width:84px;
  height:27px;
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  bottom:87px;
  left:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -o-border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  position:relative;
}
.listing .socialMedia img {
  opacity:1;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.navButton {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.navButton.active {
  background-color:#939598 !important;
}
#viewMore {
  width:126px;
  height:31px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border-radius:0;
  border-bottom-right-radius:13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:13px;
  background-color:#D1D2D4;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:31px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#reviews {
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#totalReviews {
  width:175px;
  height:176px;
  font-size:80px;
  font-weight:lighter;
  background-image:url('../images/totalReviews.png');
  line-height:176px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#A7A9AC;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  padding-right:75px;
  float:left;
}
#reviewContainer {
  width:710px;
  float:right;
}
.review {
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.reviewDisplayPic {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  margin-right:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.reviewContent {
  width:625px;
  padding:5px 5px 0 5px;
  height:65px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.reviewReadMore {
  float:right;
  width:635px;
  height:15px;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
  background-image:url('../images/Review-Read-More.png');
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.reviewReply {
  width:635px;
  float:right;
  height:45px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  position:relative;
  top:-25px;
}
.reviewReplyDisplayPic {
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  margin-right:5px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.reviewReplyContent {
  width:575px;
  padding:5px 5px 0 5px;
  height:40px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.reviewReplyReadMore {
  float:right;
  width:585px;
  height:15px;
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
  background-image:url('../images/Review-Read-More.png');
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#writeAReviewTop {
  margin-top:20px;
  float:left;
  width:175px;
  height:27px;
  border:1px solid #F15A29;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
}
#seeMore {
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
  height:27px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:27px;
  color:#F15A29;
  padding-left:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#writeAReviewContainer {
   width:175px;
   height:27px;
   float:right;
   display:inline-block;
   cursor:pointer;
}
#writeAReview {
  width:175px;
  height:27px;
  border:1px solid #F15A29;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
}
#chatBox {
  width:960px;
  height:337px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#D1D3D4;
}
```

Comment: Hello bracketsage, thanks for the update. I have included the new stylesheet and removed old references and the page is not displaying properly refresh to refresh, once again...

Please review and confirm?

Comment: My ISP (one of the big guys) had a major outage yesterday so I could not reply, but my copy is working perfectly in chrome.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2U-1jSVI5M3NFF4dG11MXJYTU0/edit?usp=sharing Here's a zip of the files that are working for me in Chrome 36.0.1985.143. Up until this point, I was able to get the same error you were getting, many many times. I can no longer, even with spam-f5ing.

**PLEASE let me know once you have downloaded this so I can delete it :)**

Comment: Download completed. I will attempt to re-host your files at a new location and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Since this thread has died and you provided a working solution (I still haven't checked your new files... Busy working...) I've upvoted and marked as completed.